# Turning Off log4j logger for HtmlUnit

Tags: java, logging, log4j, htmlunit, java-6

I've tried turning off the logger by typing the following but the server still seems to log the messages.

```
static {
    Logger htmlUnitLoggger = Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit");
    htmlUnitLoggger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    htmlUnitLoggger.setAdditivity(false);

    Logger httpLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http");
    httpLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    httpLogger.setAdditivity(false);
}
```

it seems to work my desktop but not on the server.

Comment: You're not using a log4j.property/xml file? Logs will show before the class that houses this code is instantiated. Maybe try Logger.getRootLogger().

Comment: that is correct I'm not using a log4j.properties or .xml file. I only want to turn off the log from this object. the server does have  log4j.properties file

Answer (score 2):

If you are using log4j.properties append this to the file.

```
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=OFF
log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver.cluster=OFF
log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver.connection=OFF
log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command=OFF
```

HtmlUnit use commons logging which automatically picks available logger in the project. Each class runs a logger under a name of the class. The code above will turn off each class's logger.